# Parse a particular number of lines

Tags: ruby, file-io

I'm trying to read through a file, find a certain pattern and then grabbing a set number of lines of text after the line that contains that pattern. Not really sure how to approach this.

Comment: Sounds like homework. How far have you gotten so far? Start with some pseudo-code (add it to your question), then refine it. When you have a more specific question, we're here to help.

Comment: If it's homework, it should be tagged as homework.

Comment: It's actually not homework at all, as I'm not a CS student at all, haha. I'm trying to parse the logs to a game that I play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the `n` number of lines after the line matching `pattern` in the file `filename`:

```
lines = File.open(filename) do |file|
  line = file.readline until line =~ /pattern/ || file.eof;
  file.eof ? nil : (1..n).map { file.eof ? nil : file.readline }.compact
end
```

This should handle all cases, like the pattern not present in the file (returns `nil`) or there being less than `n` lines after the matching lines (the resulting array containing the last lines of the file.)

Answer (score 1):

First parse the file into lines.  Open, read, split on the line break

```
lines = File.open(file_name).read.split("\n")
```

Then get index

```
index = line.index{|x| x.match(/regex_pattern/)}
```

Where regex_pattern is the pattern that you are looking for.  Use the index as a starting point and then the second argument is the number of lines (in this case 5)

```
lines[index, 5]
```

It will return an array of 'lines'

You could combine it a bit more to reduce the number of lines. but I was attempting to keep it readable.

Comment: Since this opens up the entire file at once would it have memory problems at all with bigger documents? (up to 5mb or so)

Comment: not so much, I use similar methods to parse log files of 500MB.

Comment: Sucking the entire file into memory is poor style, even though VM enables it.

Comment: What would be the correct style to maintain functionality but in "good style"?

Comment: lars has the answer, give it to him.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not tied to Ruby, `grep -A 12 trivet` will show the 12 lines after any line  with trivet in it.  Any regex will work in place of "trivet"

Comment: Well I actually need to still parse the following whatever lines. And extract information out of them. So grep wasn't a good fit.

Answer (score 0):

```
matched = false;
num = 0;
res = "";

new File(filename).each_line { |line|
    if (matched) {
        res += line+"\n";
        num++;
        if (num == num_lines_desired) {
            break;
        }
    } elsif (line.match(/regex/)) {
        matched = true;
    }

}
```

This has the advantage of not needing to read the whole file in the event of a match.

When done, `res` will hold the desired lines.

Comment: Holy moly. This has to be hands down the ugliest Ruby code I've ever seen. Well, actually, given the amount of syntax errors, I'd hardly even call it Ruby code.

Comment: It's CRuby!  Hey, Ruby supports block syntax.  You don't *have* to use "begin" and "end" :-P

Answer (score 0):

in rails (only difference is how I generate the file object)

```
file = File.open(File.join(Rails.root, 'lib', 'file.json'))

 #convert file into an array of strings, with \n as the separator

 line_ary = file.readlines
 line_count = line_ary.count

 i = 0
  #or however far up the document you want to be...you can get very fancy with this or just do it manually

 hsh = {} 
 line_count.times do |l|
    child_id = JSON.parse(line_ary[i])
    i += 1
    parent_ary = JSON.parse(line_ary[i])
    i += 1
    hsh[child_id] = parent_ary
  end
```

haha I've said too much that should definitely get you started